# How am i suppose to understand this ouput for join ()(using python 3)?

Tags: python, string, join

Here is the image,

[image]

Here is what i tried playing with join function but i don't get what's going on here if anyone out there encountered with same then please help me out!.

Comment: A string is an *iterable* of strings: 1-char strings that are the characters, so you `join` `HI` between the characters of `'bye'`.

Comment: Pleas don't post screenshots of your code; post the text itself.

Comment: `'HI'` is placed between every character in `'bye'`

Comment: I'm sure you read the [documentation for `join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join), so what part of it do you not understand?

Comment: were you looking for `+` operator in Python?

Comment: hey yo'll i'am new to stack overflow and programming , ik that was dumb question and dumb way of asking as well.Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Strings can be iterated through, and when you do iterate through one, it will spin through each individual letter.

[`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) will join the iterable inside the brackets together using the string outside the brackets.

If the iterable was a list, it'd be easy to see what is going on

```
>>> l = ["Alice", "Ben", "Casey"]
>>> ", ".join(l)
"Alice, Ben, Casey"
```

And with a string,

```
>>> "-".join("Hello!")
>>> # Same as "-".join(["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", "!"])
"H-e-l-l-o-!"
```

Comment: The string isn't casted into an iterable, a string _is_ an iterable.

Comment: Good catch, I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

String is a sequence of characters. Join function concatenates the sequence (iterable) to a new string by joining them on the string you called the function on. In this case it's s with value of 'HI'.

Its not different than:

```
print(" ".join("hello", "world"))
```

That results in "hello world".

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, `string.join` receives a iterable as a parameter, so the string you are passing it, will be treated as a iterable and not a string, so you will do `b`, joined with `y` joined with `e`. If you do `s.join(['bye'])`, then the output will be the one I assume you were expecting